# AS3 XMLSocket sends data from all clients started, but data recieved only by last client connected

Tags: node.js, actionscript-3, flash, sockets

AS3 XMLSocket sends data from all clients started, but data recieved only by last client connected.

I have the flash web client, and if you open for example 2 or more tabs with the app, every client will send the data to socket server, but only THE LAST client connected gets all the data. Here is the link `http://151.248.124.213/`. It has chat alike interface for now and green button is the SEND button. App gets connected when you hit stage with the mouse. App is connected when the message Connected appears in the screen. To test `http://151.248.124.213/` just open 2 or more tabs.

Here is the AS3 code:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://151.248.124.213:3843");

var socket:XMLSocket;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect);

function doConnect(evt:Event):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doConnect); 
    socket = new XMLSocket("151.248.124.213", 3000);

    socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
    socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
}

function onConnect(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("Connected");
    output_txt.text = "Connected\n";
    socket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
    socket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);

    socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);
    socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);                
}

function onSocketClose(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("Connection Closed");
    socket.removeEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onSocketClose);
    socket.removeEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onDataReceived);
}

function onError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("Connect failed");
    socket.removeEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
    socket.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
}


function onDataReceived(evt:DataEvent):void
{
    try {
        trace( "From Server:", evt.data );
        var msg = evt.data;
        output_txt.text += msg + "\n";
    }
    catch (e:Error) {
            trace('error');
    }
}

send_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, send_btn_clicked);

function send_btn_clicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{   
    var msg = input_txt.text;
    socket.send(msg);
    input_txt.text = "";
}
```

And here is the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
})
app.listen(80);

var net = require('net');

var mySocket;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    mySocket = socket;
    mySocket.on("connect", onConnect);
    mySocket.on("data", onData);
});

server.listen(3000);

function onConnect()
{
    console.log("Connected to Flash");
}

function onData(d)
{
    if(d == "exit\0")
    {
        console.log("exit");
        mySocket.end();
        server.close();
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("From Flash = " + d);
        mySocket.write(d, 'utf8');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create one socket per client on server side.

Each time a new client is connected, create a new socket. look [here](https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146) for an example.